# Plotting Intersecting Circles On A 2-D Plane

Tags: plotting

I am new to Mathematica and I would like to plot a number of circles all onto the **same** graph. I would like to visually observe which circles intersect each other. One constraint on all the circles is that the x-coordinate is always zero.

I have a list of 3-tuples (x-coordinate, y-coordinate, radius) which represent each circle. For example, (0,0,1), (0,1,5)... I am not sure how construct the circle intersections using the `Plot` command.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

```
triples = Table[{0, RandomInteger[5], RandomReal[]}, {5}];
(* {{0,4,0.676806},{0,5,0.377882},{0,2,0.421773},{0,4,0.631164},{0,3, 0.820832}} *)

opts = {Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 6}}, Frame -> False, 
      ImageSize -> 150, AspectRatio -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> Thick};
```

**Graphics**

```
g1 = Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Circle[{#, #2}, #3]} & @@@ triples, opts];
```

**Graphics / Translate / Scale**

```
g2 = Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Translate[Scale[Circle[], #3], {#, #2}]}&@@@ triples,
  opts]
```

**ContourPlot**

```
g3 = ContourPlot[Evaluate[(x - #)^2 + (y - #2)^2 == #3^2 & @@@ triples], 
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 6}, Evaluate[opts], ContourStyle->Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {5}]];
```

**ParametricPlot**

```
g4 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[(#3 { Cos[t], Sin[t]} + {#, #2}) & @@@ triples], 
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Evaluate[opts], PlotStyle->Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {5}]];

Row[Labeled[##, Top] & @@@ {{g1, "Graphics"}, {g2, "Graphics/ Translate/ Scale"}, 
   {g3, "ContourPlot"}, {g4, "ParametricPlot"}}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: The colour coding is a great idea.

Comment: @I.K., btw, if you have version 10, you can use `RandomColor[]` instead of `Hue[RandomReal[]]`.

Comment: Yes I do. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics[
   Circle @@@ ({{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]} & /@ 
   {{0, 2, 3}, {0, 4, 6}, {0, 12, 9}})
         ]
```

Comment: I've corrected my post as I think it was misleading. Even though I have 3-tuples to represent each circle in my problem specification, I did not necessarily want to pass that exact structure into the plotting commands. Sorry to mislead but I did up vote your answer as it pointed me in the right direction as I thought I needed to use the `Plot` command to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`Show[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Circle[{1, 1}, 2]}], Axes -> True]`

[image]